# Username checking not working for form with multiple register models (mvc)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, remote-validation

I have a page which allows an admin to add multiple users to the database at once, with usernames and passwords. I use remote username checking, so in my account models I have this:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Remote("doesUserNameExist", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; } 

// ...etc

}
```

In my account controller I have this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult doesUserNameExist(string UserName)
    {

        var user = Membership.GetUser(UserName);
        return Json(user == null);
    }
```

Now this works nicely on a single form, with one user being created, using the mvc html helpers. The message saying that a username is in use shows up as I'm typing it into the field. But on this form which doesn't use the mvc helpers, instead pure html and javascript, it doesn't show up:

```
@model List<PicsWebApp.Models.UserRegisterModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "NewRep";
}

<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1>First-Time Setup</h1>
</div>
<legend></legend>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h3>Add Representatives <small>You can add more representatives later</small></h3>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("NewRep", "Admin", new { jobid = ViewData["jobid"] }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form" }))
    {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <p>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="btn btn-warning">Skip</a>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add">Add Rep</button>
        </p>
        <div id="fieldform" class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="container0" class="col-lg-4" style="background-color: #eee; border: 4px solid white;">
                <h4 style="text-align: center">New Rep</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Representative Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="models[0].RepName" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Contact Number</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="models[0].ContactNumber" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Rep Username</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="models[0].UserName" />
                    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-remote="User name already exists. Please enter a different user name." data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.UserName" data-val-remote-type="POST" data-val-remote-url="/Account/doesUserNameExist" data-val-required="The User name field is required." id="UserName" name="models[0].UserName" type="text">
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Location</label><select id="select-0" class="form-control" name="models[0].Location"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Rep Password</label><input type="password" class="form-control" name="models[0].Password" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Confirm Password</label><input type="password" class="form-control" name="models[0].ConfirmPassword" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var selectValues = {
        "Johannesburg": "Johannesburg",
        "Pretoria": "Pretoria",
        "Cape Town": "Cape Town",
        "Pretoria": "Pretoria",
        "Durban": "Durban",
        "Centurion": "Centurion"
    };

    $.each(selectValues, function (key, value) {
        $('select')
             .append($('<option>', { value: key })
             .text(value))
             .prop("selectedIndex", -1);
    });

    var i = 1;
    $("#add").click(function () {
        var inputfield = '<div class="col-lg-4" id="' + container + i + '" style="background-color: #eee; border: 4px solid white;"><h4 style="text-align: center">New Rep</h4><div class="form-group"><label>Representative Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="models[' + i + '].RepName" /></div>' +
           '<div class="form-group"><label>Contact Number</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="models[' + i + '].ContactNumber" /></div>' +
                '<div class="form-group"><label>Rep Username</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="models[' + i + '].UserName" /></div>' +
                    '<div class="form-group"><label>Location</label><select id="select-' + i + '" class="form-control" name="models[' + i + '].Location"></select></div>' +
                        '<div class="form-group"><label>Rep Password</label><input type="password" class="form-control" name="models[' + i + '].Password" /></div>' +
                            '<div class="form-group"><label>Confirm Password</label><input type="password" class="form-control" name="models[' + i + '].ConfirmPassword"/></div></div>'
        $('#fieldform').append(inputfield)

        $.each(selectValues, function (key, value) {
            $('#select-' + i)
                 .append($('<option>', { value: key })
                 .text(value))
                 .prop("selectedIndex", -1);
        });
        i++
    });

</script>
```

I understand I would have to add validation attributes to the username input fields but I tried that and it still didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could validate in your controller (when the ajax request is sent) using the Validator class.  This class allows you to call Validator.TryValidateObject to validate your model's data annotations such as [Required].

Then once this has passed/failed return the constructed json data with success/error messages.

Here is the article that really helped me on this:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx